# Put checkbox in rounded

Tags: checkbox, rounded-corners

I would like to put my checkbox in rounded CSS like this :

[image]

How can I do this in CSS only ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We're here to *help*, not provide free work.

Comment: Obviously I sought , I have tried before this.

Comment: Adding your code to the post will help us help you.

Comment: I wrote this one hour ago : `I work this this link : jsfiddle.net/achudars/8wW74 If I add border-radius: 200px; in ".styled-checkbox + label:before, .lt-ie8 .checkbox-replacement {" it will be ok, no ? `

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this. However, it required quite a bit of CSS.

[Here is a JSFiddle of a rounded checkbox.](https://jsfiddle.net/29yq0z4m/)

Note that rather than simply having an input, your checkbox must take this format:

```
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-circle">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1">
    Testing
</label>
</div>
```

Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox) that you can reference for all of the information regarding this checkbox.

Comment: I don't use twitter-Bootstrap :-(

Comment: I thought you had this working from your comments? Here is the final product of a hybrid between this question and your other question: http://jsfiddle.net/8wW74/179/

Answer (score 0):

Add a border-radius in CSS style is sufficient ?

Comment: the CSS property border-radius does not work for checkboxes

Comment: I work this this link : http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/8wW74/   If I add    border-radius: 200px; in ".styled-checkbox + label:before,
.lt-ie8 .checkbox-replacement {" it will be ok, no ?